# Simplest way of determining process bitness on Solaris and Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, process, solaris

I'm looking for a simple and reliable way of determining the bitness of a running process using standard shell commands.

While I've seen solution for Solaris and Linux I'd like to find one solution that works for both for extra simplicity, reliability and portability.

In Linux this can be done using `/proc/$PID/exe`, `/proc/$PID/maps`, `/proc/$PID/auxv` for example but these methods are either not present on Solaris or cannot easily be invoked from `sh`.

In Solaris a way of doing this is `pflags $PID` however `pflags` is not installed on most stock Linux distributions.

Comment: how about `lscpu`?

Comment: On Solaris `lscpu: command not found`. Also, I am trying to find the bitness of a running process, not the hardware that I have on the machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Solaris, the utility `/bin/pflags` will give you the information you need:

```
    $ /bin/pflags $$ | fgrep "data model"
            data model = _ILP32  flags = ORPHAN|MSACCT|MSFORK
```

`_ILP32` is a 32-bit process, while `_LP64` is a 64-bit process.

On Linux, there is nothing directly similar. You may want to check the very complete answer there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106234/determine-if-a-specific-process-is-32-or-64-bit

Answer (score 1):

`file /proc/<pid>/object/a.out` will tell you the bitness of a Solaris process